# Python in place object update in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In Python >= 3.5:

```
x = np.zeros((2,3))
for x_e in x:
    x_e += 123
```

This operation returns a `2x3` matrix of all `123`'s. Whereas the following returns all zeros:

```
x = np.zeros((2,3))
for x_e in x:
    x_e = 123
```

This is a little off putting to me since `x_e` is an element from `x` and it doesn't totally feel like `x` is being updated.

Okay, I think this is a thing, and it is called 'in place' update? (similar to an in place algorithm?)

But, the jarring thing is this does not work with lists:

```
x = [0,0,0]
for x_e in x:
    x_e += 123
```

This returns the list

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

I would appreciate if someone can enlighten me on what precisely is happening here.

Comment: Possible dups : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python

Comment: @Divakar, Thanks for the pointers. But I believe they do not answer the third point about immutability of integers. Also, believe me that I couldn't find them when I was searching the internet for an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet you perform an in-place addition on a `ndarray` object. Since each `x_e` is an `ndarray` the inplace operation succeeds and alters the elements.

In the second snippet you're just reassinging to the loop-variable. Nothing is performed on the elements of `x`.

In the third snippet you don't have a multidimentional list so each `x_e` is actually an `int`. Using `+=` on an `int` doesn't change in-place, it returns a new integer object (which you don't store).

The following might be more related to the first:

```
x = [[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(3)]
for x_e in x:
    x_e += [123]
```

here each element of `x` is a `list` object `[0, 0, 0]` on which you add, in-place, the element `123`. After executing, `x` will be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 123], [0, 0, 0, 123], [0, 0, 0, 123]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I wanted to clarify. But, can I ask why we are not able to change an `int` in-place?

Comment: @CemS. because `int` objects are immutable, the designers of the language made that decision early on since there's many benefits to it.

Comment: @Kasramvd, Thanks! This sheds light on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have that:

```
>>> x = np.array(range(5))
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

So now:

```
>>> x+123
array([123, 124, 125, 126, 127])
```

As you can see the '+' action is mapped to the array. So when you do 
create an array full of 0's and add 123 to the sub lists the array is consisted of is logical to have the above result.

Comment: Yeah but, why doesn't the in place for loop operation work with lists? What is new to me is the in place operation in the for loop. I do understand the broadcasting as I am coming from Matlab.

Comment: @CemS. That's because you are changing a mutable object within `for` loop which is the sub-list of the main list and changing a mutable object, which is a reference to the original object and any change on it will affect the original object as well.

Comment: @CemS., yes in python lists and numpy arrays is not the same thing. For example another big difference a list has over an array is that built-in functions (like sum) are performed much faster  in lists than arrays. We just use np.arrays for big data

Comment: @coder In this case they are the same, this is only matter of mutability not their functionalities.

Comment: @Kasramvd, yes I agree I just wanted to clarify that the general case is that lists and numpy arrays are not always the same thing