# Difference between assignment and compound operators in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please look into the code below

```
def double(arg):
    print("Before: ", arg)
    arg = arg * 2
    print("After: ", arg)
```

I was studying Head first Python, and I came to this section where they were discussing about pass by value and pass by reference.
If we invoke above function with a list as argument such as:

```
num = [1,2,3]
double(num)
print(num)
```

The output is :-

```
Before:  [1, 2, 3]
After:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which seems fine, considering the fact that **arg** in function double is a new object reference. So the value of **num** did not change.

But if I use compound operators instead of assignment operators, things work differently as shown:

```
def double(arg):
    print("Before: ", arg)
    arg *= 2
    print("After: ", arg)

num = [1,2,3]
double(num)
print(num)
```

The output that I get for this is:

```
Before:  [1, 2, 3]
After:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Why does this happen? I used to think a*=2 and a = a*2 are same. But what's going on in here?

Thanks

Comment: Also related: [When is “i += x” different from “i = i + x” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376509/846892)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difference between mutable and immutable objects.  A mutable object can implement `obj *= something` by actually modifying the object in place; an immutable object can only return a new object with the updated value (in which case the result is identical to `obj = obj * something`).  The compound assignment statements can handle either case, it's entirely up to the object's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

a *= 2 modifies the structure itself (a) whereas a = a*2 reassigns a as a new variable.

(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop))