# FLOP count of "x += y" vs. "x = x + y"

Tags: python, c++, time

In languages like `C++`, there is an expression like `x += y`.

If `x` had already been occupied by a specific floating number (e.g. `3.0`), is there any FLOP count difference between the following two?

- 1. `x += 1.0`
- 2. `x = x + 1.0`

---

### Edited

To be specific, in languages such as `Python`, there is indeed the difference between

- x+= 1.0
- x = x+1.0

where the first indicates the modification of the data-structure itself, and the second corresponds to the reassignment of the variable. (Reference : [What is the difference between i=i+1 and i+=1 in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop)

For `FLOP` counts, one may be interested in the following two things:

- the number of `+`s
- the number of `*`s

so it might be natural for a novice to `C++` as me to wonder about the difference between the FLOP counts of the two.

As the answerer points out, the difference can show up even in `C++` when we use `volatile` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C and C++ do not say anything about CPU operations. Both languages specify the behavior of the expressions, not how they're implemented.

The behavior of `x = x + 1.0` and `x += 1.0` are identical, except that any side effects of evaluating `x` occur twice in the former and once in the later. If `x` is the name of a non-`volatile` object, then there is no semantic difference, and any decent compiler should generate exactly the same code for both.

Differences can show up if you write something like:

```
arr[func()] = arr[func()] + 1.0;
```

vs

```
arr[func()] ++;
```