# in python what is the difference of eq_list += tuple1 and eq_list = eq_list + tuple1?

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, I have tuple, to convert tuple to list i use

```
tuple1 = (1,2,3,4,5)
eq_list = []
eq_list += tuple1
```

it works fine.But if i use :

```
eq_list = eq_list + tuple1
```

it gives TypeError **can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list**
why that? isn't  a += b equivalent a = a + b?

Comment: You need to convert tuple to list before you add. eq_list = eq_list + list(tuple1).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446833/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-1-and-i-1-in-a-for-loop

Comment: "Isn't a += b equivalent to a = a + b?" Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is implemented using `list.__add__`, which expects both arguments to be instance of `list`.

```
eq_list = eq_list + tuple1  # eq_list = list.__add__(eq_list, tuple1)
```

`+=` is implemented using `list.__iadd__`, which expects only the first argument to be an instance of `list`; the second argument can be any iterable object.

```
eq_list += tuple1  # eq_list = list.__iadd__(eq_list, tuple1)
```

---

`a += b` and `a = a + b` are only equivalent when `__iadd__` isn't defined for the given type. For example, `tuple.__iadd__` isn't defined, so given `x = ()`, both `x = x + ()` and `x += ()` are implemented with `x = x.__add__(())`.